# gdalinfo authenticate for remote file

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am trying to access the metadata for the following COG (Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF) using

```
gdalinfo /vsicurl/https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/data/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2022/082/070/LC09_L2SR_082070_20220427_20220429_02_T1/LC09_L2SR_082070_20220427_20220429_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF
```

But this resulted in error

```
ERROR 4: `/vsicurl/https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/data/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2022/082/070/LC09_L2SR_082070_20220427_20220429_02_T1/LC09_L2SR_082070_20220427_20220429_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/vsicurl/https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/data/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2022/082/070/LC09_L2SR_082070_20220427_20220429_02_T1/LC09_L2SR_082070_20220427_20220429_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF'.
```

I tried importing in QGIS (with credentials) as well but it resulted in same error.
[image]

I am able to download the file when I paste the url in browser (it asks for credentials using server `ers.cr.usgs.gov` and on successful login, it downloads the file)

The url is taken from [stacindex.org](https://stacindex.org/catalogs/usgs-landsat-collection-2-api#/item/2JPDvmUNLrbmMRzXjWUvRj55bD7fvYTS9snbwLAUSTp3v9v2tPSsiy/AJuF2U3iorVsbj3zAw9hAkdVYLdh3kjZ1HV8TfPthGbWUYbFBwpTSFxZzvkkoSC6Qu9DvULevu?si=0&t=2#8/-14.462111/167.138964)

How to pass in the credentials so GDAL can authenticate?

**Update**: I tried passing config options as mentioned in mailing list [here](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2021-October/054728.html) but it still results in the same error

```
 gdalinfo  /vsicurl/https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/data/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2022/082/070/LC09_L2SR_082070_20220427_20220429_02_T1/LC09_L2SR_082070_20220427_20220429_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF --config GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN EMPTY_DIR --config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE ON --config CPL_VSIL_CURL_USE_HEAD FALSE --config GDAL_HTTP_COOKIEFILE /tmp/cookies.txt --config GDAL_HTTP_COOKIEJAR /tmp/cookies.txt --config CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS TIF
```

GDAL 3.3.3

Comment: What about downloading the data via wget or curl and then pass it to gdlainfo ? or are you interested in getting metadata without downloading the file ?

Answer (score 3):

For those who stumble upon this query, here is the workaround.

GDAL throws this error because the response from the URL is not a TIFF but an html document asking the user to login. We need to send a POST request to login first and subsequently do a GET request to get the actual TIFF. I don't know how you'd do that in shell script but here is the python version.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://ers.cr.usgs.gov/login' # this is end point for login
with requests.Session() as s:
    
  r = s.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
  sval = soup.find('input', attrs={'name':'csrf'})['value']
  
  data = {"username": "MYUSERNAME", # change your username and password
      "password": "MYPASSWORD",
      "csrf": sval}

  bf= s.post(url, data = data)
  print(bf.status_code)
  respb = s.get('https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/data/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2022/089/089/LC09_L2SP_089089_20220428_20220430_02_T1/LC09_L2SP_089089_20220428_20220430_02_T1_SR_B1.TIF',
              allow_redirects=True,
              headers = {'content-type': 'image/tiff'})
  with open('output.tif', 'wb') as src:
    src.write(respb.content)
```