# How to authenticate to download images from https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, authentication, usgs, stac

I am building a QGIS plugin in Python to fetch Landsat images from this STAC server:
https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server

I need to be able to download the thumbnails, but cannot find how to authenticate to do this programmatically. How can I authenticate to get this thumbnail jpeg using vanilla python (or standard included libs)?

Trying to fetch the url redirects to the USGS login page.

https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/data/collection02/level-2/standard/etm/2000/215/021/LE07_L2SR_215021_20000214_20211117_02_T2/LE07_L2SR_215021_20000214_20211117_02_T2_thumb_small.jpeg

NB:  I do not want to use any extra python libraries that are not supplied with QGIS as it makes sharing the plugin more complex.

This is where I get redirected when attempting to download: https://ers.cr.usgs.gov/login?redirectUrl=https://ers.cr.usgs.gov/?redirect_url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flandsatlook.usgs.gov%252Fdata%252Fcollection02%252Flevel-2%252Fstandard%252Foli-tirs%252F2019%252F109%252F073%252FLC08_L2SP_109073_20190527_20200828_02_T1%252FLC08_L2SP_109073_20190527_20200828_02_T1_thumb_small.jpeg

I do not want to use web scraping.

Comment: You may need to drop a netrc with credentials in the working dir or user profile dir. That's what the various  USGS NASA tutorials I've seen do.

Comment: Thanks @user2856 feel free to post as an answer if you would like the points

Comment: @user2856 this is actually not working in this case. I get redirected to the USGS EROS Registration Page not Earth Data as per those tutorials. I get redirected here: https://ers.cr.usgs.gov/login?redirectUrl=https://ers.cr.usgs.gov/?redirect_url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flandsatlook.usgs.gov%252Fdata%252Fcollection02%252Flevel-2%252Fstandard%252Foli-tirs%252F2019%252F109%252F073%252FLC08_L2SP_109073_20190527_20200828_02_T1%252FLC08_L2SP_109073_20190527_20200828_02_T1_thumb_small.jpeg

Comment: Ugh, they don't make it easy :(

Comment: I know, I cant fathom why its so hard to find documentation on this!

Comment: It looks like no authentication is required to access the tiles here: https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/dynamic-tiler/scenes/LC08_L1TP_100011_20230912_20230912_02_RT/tiles/7/125/28.png?layer=natural_color

Comment: @ComradeChe so are you thinking a solution could be to modify the urls returned by the STAC server at https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server and make requests for scenes and thumbnails to https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/dynamic-tiler ? I think these might be precut tiles for a WMS server, note the x,y,z in the url... So its interesting that there is no auth required, but I dont think it will work for us to get thumbnails and whole landsat scene download urls

Comment: If your task is to load Landsat space images, then in my opinion your decision to refuse to use third-party libraries is questionable. But it is your choice @staf Have you read the machine API for USGS/EROS? https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/api/docs/json/

Comment: @ComradeChe this is because Im building this as a QGIS Plugin and it can be hard to distribute a plugin that relies on third party packages. Does that make you question my decision less? Im having a look at that documentation now, but its unclear how it relates to the STAC compliant API at https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server . Can you explain how the two are related? Thanks for your input!

Comment: https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/api/docs/json/ and https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server are different ways to get Landsat data.

Comment: Thanks @ComradeChe we need to use the STAC server for this as it feeds into another project evolving around STAC. Ill have a good look at the m2m service for other projects, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inelegant solution is to login to USGS using a POST request first and get the image using BeautifulSoup or another web scraping tool. I would prefer not to do this, and instead authenticate directly in the request if possible. An example that works is documented here: [gdalinfo authenticate for remote file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430026/gdalinfo-authenticate-for-remote-file)